# Have emacs highlight characters over 80?

Tags: emacs

I have seen some solutions on here which will highlight an entire line if it goes beyond 80 characters, and also to do a `line-wrap` once the line becomes greater than 80. What I would like to do is to edit my `.emacs` file so that any character beyond 80 takes on a different background. So the first 80 characters will have my current emacs background, then characters > 80 would have  a black background say. Can someone point me in the right directions? Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I recently wrote an [extensive article](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/05/31/highlight-lines-that-exceed-a-certain-length-limit/) on the subject. Here's the gist of it:

```
(require 'whitespace)
(setq whitespace-line-column 80) ;; limit line length
(setq whitespace-style '(face lines-tail))

(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'whitespace-mode)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, just what I wanted!

Comment: Very nice.  This is should really go into the whitespace-mode documentation string so it's available in emacs.

Comment: Nice trick! Is there anyway to make white-space auto highlights characters other than ASCII? I have come across this situation many times because there are so many Unicode characters look like ASCII ones.

Comment: This solution will make showing tab/spaces in this buffer impossible.

Comment: Where should I enter these commands?

Comment: @srgsanky You can put them in your `init.el`.

Comment: Do not reccomend, the setting of the `whitespace-style` variable makes `whitespace-cleanup` no longer work

Answer (score 7):

Here are some other solutions that people use, in addition to the one that @BozhidarBatsov mentions:

- Library [`column-marker.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColumnMarker) -- highlight any column(s)
- Library [`fill-column-indicator.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FillColumnIndicator) -- highlight the fill column
- Library [`mode-line-posn.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeLinePosition) -- highlight column number in mode line when greater than limit
- Library [`wide-column.el`](http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/phillip.lord/download/emacs/wide-column.el) -- highlight cursor when column passes limit

See also:

- [FindLongLines](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FindLongLines)
- [HighlightLongLines](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLongLines)
- [EightyColumnRule](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EightyColumnRule)
- [MarginMode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MarginMode)

(FWIW, my personal preference is [`mode-line-posn.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeLinePosition) --- less intrusive, just the right amount of indication.)