# Enforce 79 characters per line in emacs?

Tags: python, emacs, coding-style

I wonder if encorcing 79 characters per line in Python code can be done automatically and intelligently in emacs?
By intelligently, I mean it can break a long line of code at a proper place.

If not possible to do that automatically, can it be done somehow semi-automatically, or more convenient than completely manually (e.g. counting characters per line manually)?

By the way, I assume 79 characters per line is a good practice. If I am wrong, feel free to correct me.

Thanks.

Comment: "I assume 79 characters per line is a good practice. If I am wrong, feel free to correct me." Keeping lines to a maximum of 79 characters is [the official style recommendation for Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length).

Comment: how do you do it? @Chris?

Comment: I wasn't offering a solution to your main question; I was simply confirming that you've got the right idea to wrap at 79 characters. choroba's comment is one valid option. It's not super intelligent, but it should get the job done.

Comment: Another solution is to make all of your windows 80 characters wide, and then anything in the rightmost column (except the cursor) shouldn't be there.  `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(width . 80))`

Comment: auto-fill-mode won't do this. Pls, read documentation or try it before answering. fill-mode will redistribute '/n' to any previous white space (if it exists) in that line to not exceed 80, it WON'T add a new '\n' automatically which is what this question is about.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is good practice, there are a lot of solutions out there, but they are not "automatic", most rely on simply showing you when you'e passed the limit, not making the change for you.

One "automatic" solution is the built in `auto-fill-mode`.

For further ideas/discussion:

Read this article on the Emacs Wiki: [EightyColumnRule](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EightyColumnRule)

It offers several non-automatic ways to help you keep your lines less then 80 chars.

`whitespace-mode` is built in to emacs has the capacity to highlight all lines that are longer than a certain length.

`column-marker` can be used to draw a line down your buffer at a certain column.

[column-enforce-mode](https://github.com/jordonbiondo/column-enforce-mode/) (I am the author of this) can work like `whitespace-mode` except it will only highlight text further than 80 columns on a line, not the entire line.

There is a lot of discussion on this topic to go through and more solutions to find:

[How can I make emacs highlight lines that go over 80 chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344474/how-can-i-make-emacs-highlight-lines-that-go-over-80-chars)

[Have emacs highlight characters over 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855510/have-emacs-highlight-characters-over-80)

http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/05/31/highlight-lines-that-exceed-a-certain-length-limit/

Here is a custom solution I have in my init that sets the current buffer's margins such that the editable space in the buffer is only 80 columns wide. I.e you know when you've passed the limit when your text goes to the next line.

```lisp
(defun toggle-80-editting-columns-balanced (&optional columns)
  "Set both window margins so the edittable space is only 80 columns."
  (interactive "p")
  (let ((margins (window-margins)))
    (if (or (car margins) (cdr margins))
        (set-window-margins nil 0 0)
      (let* ((change (max (- (window-width) (or columns 80)) 0))
             (left (/ change 2))
             (right (- change left)))
        (set-window-margins nil left right)))))
```

Comment: auto-fill-mode won't do this. Pls, read documentation or try it before answering. fill-mode will redistribute '/n' to any previous white space (if it exists) in that line to not exceed 80, it WON'T add a new '\n' automatically which is what this question is about